# Async react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I would like create async React hook in React-Native for get AsyncStorage data before run my fetch.

Example :

```
const useCallApi = async url => {
  const [instance, token] = await Promise.all([
    AsyncStorage.getItem('instance'),
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
  ]);

  const data = useFetch(`${instance}/api/v1/${url}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  });

  return data;
};

export default useCallApi;
```

But this hook return an error `Unhandled promise rejection`. I think the problem is `await` before [useFetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-suspense) hook, but how i can fix this case ?

If anyone can help me :)

Thank you community,

Comment: can you share a sandbox or result of Promise.all

Answer (score 1):

Why not use AsyncStorage in another way? Only after initialization is complete, you can access AsyncStorage synchronously from anywhere.Through [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md), you can operate AsyncStorage like this

```
import { XStorage } from 'react-native-easy-app';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

 export const RNStorage = {
     token: undefined, 
     isShow: undefined, 
     userInfo: undefined
 };

const initCallback = () => {

     // From now on, you can write or read the variables in RNStorage synchronously

     // equal to [console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem('isShow'))]
     console.log(RNStorage.isShow); 

     // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('token',TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3==') ]
     RNStorage.token = 'TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3=='; 

     // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('userInfo',JSON.stringify({ name:'rufeng', age:30})) ]
     RNStorage.userInfo = {name: 'rufeng', age: 30}; 
};

XStorage.initStorage(RNStorage, AsyncStorage, initCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding `await` before `AsyncStorage` helps you:

```
const useCallApi = async url => {
  const [instance, token] = await Promise.all([
    await AsyncStorage.getItem('instance'),
    await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
  ]);

  const data = useFetch(`${instance}/api/v1/${url}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  });

  return data;
};

export default useCallApi;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const useCallApi = async url => {
let instance = null;
let token = null;
  Promise.all([
    AsyncStorage.getItem('instance'),
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
  ]).then(d=>{
instance = d[0];
token = d[1];
}).catch(e=>throw e);
  const data = useFetch(`${instance}/api/v1/${url}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  });
  return data;
};

export default useCallApi;
```

I think a promise needs then when it resolve and a catch for error catching

Answer (score 0):

You should not implement the hooks like that, it will cause call fetch many times whenever the component which uses this hook re-render.
Try this instead:

```js
const useCallApi =  url => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() =>{
    const fetchData = async () =>{
      const [instance, token] = await Promise.all([
        AsyncStorage.getItem('instance'),
        AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
      ]);
      
      // I assume that your useFetch is a hook that retruen a Promise of data
      const fetchedData = await useFetch(`${instance}/api/v1/${url}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });

      setData(fetchedData)
    }
    fetchData()
  },[url])

  return data;
};
```

Comment: Hi Tony ! How it can work without run fetchData function ?

Comment: My bad, Just call it inside `useEffect`. Please check my updated comments